# How to check if a file exists in Firebase Storage from Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I have tried several different ways to check if a file exists in the firebase Storage. But this one shows the debug text

```
        if (storage.GetReferenceFromUrl($"gs://xxxxx-xxxxx-342352503.appspot.com/{fUser.UserId}") == null)
            Debug.Log("File Not Exist");
    else
        Debug.Log("File Exists");
```

which shows the file Exists. And then, I deleted the file and checked once again. but it still shows the File Exists.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage.GetReferenceFromUrl` is always going to return a non-null reference, even if the file doesn't exist.  The existence of a reference object doesn't mean that a file exists.  A reference is just a pointer to a location with a path and doesn't know if there is a file for that path.

If you want to check if a file exists, you can simply download the file using a reference or URL, or perhaps with [GetDownloadUrlAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/storage-reference#getdownloadurlasync) to see if the file has a download URL at all.

Comment: If you have a new question, post it separately.